# What is the maximum virtual depth achievable in a printed hologram?

Tags: optics, experimental-technique, hologram

I remember a few years ago printed holograms were quite fashionable. Even though they still had different colors from reality, I found them quite impressing.

I wonder if there has been any progress in this technology. In particular, I would like to know what is the current state of the art for the maximum visual depth achievable in a printed hologram?